# MVVM Binding popover isOpen in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, popup

I have a data-grid bound to an observable collection.  I want to have a mouse-enter event on a button show some content that is retrieved from a database.

To improve efficiency, I want to get this data on mouse-hover, so the initial renders are faster.

I have bound the mouse-enter and mouse-leave events to ICommand's, in the ViewModel.  These console log the mouse-enter, mouse-leave row ids correctly (mouse-leave omitted for brevity)

If I manually enter the isOpen="true" all the popovers show as expected.

The problem I have is if i mutate the Observable collection in the command delegate, the data-grid it isn't updating the contents.  The Observable collection appears to be correct in the debugger.

```
//Conditions.cs
public class Condition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool PopupOpen { get; set; }
    public string PopupContent { get; set; }
    …
}
```

ViewModel

```
    private ObservableCollection<Condition> _conditionsObservableCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Condition> ConditionsObservableCollection
    {
        get => _conditionsObservableCollection;
        set
        {
            _conditionsObservableCollection = value;
            DynamicOnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ICommand _showConditionChildrenMouseEnterCommand;
    public ICommand ShowConditionChildrenMouseEnterCommand=> _showConditionChildrenMouseEnterCommand ??
        (_showConditionChildrenMouseEnterCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(ShowConditionChildren));

    private void ShowConditionChildren(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter:"+id); // this is output correctly.
        foreach (Condition condition in ConditionsObservableCollection)
        {
            condition.PopupOpen = condition.Id == id;
        }
        //ConditionsObservableCollection appears to be changed here.
        OnPropertyChanged("ConditionsObservableCollection");
    }
```

BaseViewModel

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void DynamicOnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));          
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

DataGrid Column

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Info">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Id}"
                                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowConditionChildrenMouseEnterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                            />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Id}"
                                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.HideConditionChildrenMouseLeaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                            />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="InformationVariant"/>
                </Button>
                <Popup
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    IsOpen="{Binding PopupOpen}">
                    <StackPanel Background="AntiqueWhite">
                        <TextBlock  Padding="5">Here is a popup for id: <Run Text="{Binding Id}"/></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Condition : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    private bool popUpOpen;
    public bool PopUpOpen
    {
        get { return popUpOpen; }
        set
        {
            popUpOpen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PopUpOpen");
        }
     }
    public string PopupContent { get; set; }
    …
}
```

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged also in your class. Your viewmodel notify only the change to the item of your ObservableCollection, in terms of item added and removed. If you want to notify the change of the internal properties you have to do this

Answer (score 0):

Condition should implement INotifyPropertyChanged..

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, the view model is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.  Condition is a simple class used by the ObservableCollection which is bound to the xaml.  So the observable collection is changed and has the PropertyChangedEventHandler.